# Links to a box within the page

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, box

I usually see in some sites a vertical navigation menu and these link are applied to a box in the page but not `<iframe>` tag.
can anyone help.
and thank you

Comment: You will need to post an example, for us to have any idea what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you try to telling a loading divs without refresing the page. We call it as Single page application like Gmail. You can done this by several way.

1. Do this manually by calling ajex and load divs from host. All events handle by separate JS function.
2. Try frameworks.

   *Backend frameworks like struct2 comes with this capability so this method you have to code in backend

   *Frontend frameworks like angularjs support route functionality can achive this result. So you have to deal with JS in front end this time.

Example in angular js

```js
var app = angular.module( "myApp", [] );

app.config( function ( $routeProvider ) {
  $routeProvider
    .when( '/this', { templateUrl: 'this.html' } )
    .when( '/that', { templateUrl: 'that.html' } )
    .when( '/other', { templateUrl: 'other.html' } )
    .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/this' } );
});

app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
});
```

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="this.html">
  This Page.
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="that.html">
  That Page.
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="other.html">
  Other Page.
</script>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/this">This</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/that">That</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/other">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

j fiddle code>> http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NEuJ6/

Comment: it is a box next to navigation menu that applies the link to it.

Comment: Add some examples here?

Comment: what i mean that if some one will click the exmpla links it will show up in the box

Comment: I tried to compose the same example to my website but it didn't worked.